# Spring Integration - split() and aggregate() stats

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Is there a way to know the `split()` and `aggregate()` stats by enabling additional logging level or so? We have 10k messages being split and processed for 2+ hours, any stats as what is going on will help.

Comment: need to know more context on this?
What type of stats you are expecting ?

Comment: Like processing x / xxxx every so and so duration. Or a periodic pending count. I know we can add an `Advice` to `split()`, however not sure what type of advice shall give me the stats